# Initializing object of derived class using initializer-list

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

I got a `struct B` that is derived from a `struct A`.

```
struct A{
  int a;  
};

struct B : public A{
    int b;
};
```

Is there a straight way to initialize an object of type `B` without providing a constructor, let's say using initializer-list?

*Some more insight*:

I got two `struct`s that I use to pass data between threads; the second one holds the same data as the first one, with the addition of some *synchronization variable*. I could make the first `struct` a data member of the second one, or just duplicate the declaration of data members in the second `struct`, to easily use the initializer-list; but I think that *in this particular application* it would be logically more correct that the second `struct` extends the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an extremely concise solution, but there *is* a solution at least:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct B : A
{
    int b;

    template <typename ...Args,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<
                             std::is_constructible<A, Args&&...>::value>
    B(int x, Args &&... args)
    : b(x), A(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    { }
};
```

This solution isn't exactly short, but it is general. The new constructor for `B` exists only in those specializations which make sense, thanks to the enable-if SFINAE, so `B` is precisely as constructible as it can be.

There is one more danger here that I didn't address, namely how `explicit` the new constructor should be. Ideally it should be as explicit as the matching `A` constructor, but that's a bit hard to detect programatically (as done in [N4064](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4064) for pairs and tuples).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aggregate initialization for `B`, because it's not an aggregate, as per [dcl.init.aggr]/1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or
>   protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Update: Kerrek SB provided a good solution using template constructor, but if you like, you can add quite straightforward non-template constructor for `B`:

```
struct B : public A{
    int b;
    B(const A& a_, int b_) : A(a_), b(b_) {}
};
```

And use it with one extra pair of braces:

```
B b {{3}, 5};
```